# The difference between the "For testing purposes only" and "Test Mode"

Tags: windows-10

What is the difference between the "For testing purposes only" and the "Test Mode" modes in Windows 10 and can I set the test mode where the secure boot is turned on?

Comment: I haven't tested either of these modes yet, but I assume it won't let you because it sort of defeats the purpose of Secure Boot...

Comment: Where have you come across both and how do you trigger them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Test Mode** is shown when test signing is enabled on a PC.
This is done by running `bcdedit /set testsigning on` from an UAC-elevated command prompt.

Test signing is used to allow developers to load drivers they are still working on that have not yet been code signed with an official certificate.  This is one of the steps we need to do when loading test fixes.
For more information on Test Signing, see the article
[What is Test Mode & how to remove Test Mode watermark in Windows](https://www.thewindowsclub.com/what-is-test-mode-and-how-to-remove-test-mode-watermark-in-windows-7).

**For testing purposes only** usually appears as a result of installing a fix during
the course of a Microsoft Support case.
The purpose of this message is to remind users that code that Microsoft Support
has asked them to test has been installed on the system,
code which may not have yet undergone full testing.
It may also appear when installing a pre-release Microsoft product.

Source: [For testing purposes only, and other desktop watermarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/archive/blogs/ntdebugging/for-testing-purposes-only-and-other-desktop-watermarks).

See also the article
[Desktop Watermarks: The Difference Between “For Testing Purposes Only” and “Test Mode”](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/3160.desktop-watermarks-the-difference-between-for-testing-purposes-only-and-test-mode.aspx),
where Microsoft explains the mechanism of causing this text to be displayed.